# Использовать куки в Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie, selenium

Как в Selenium использовать куки? Например, когда открываешь Firefox через него, то там не выполнен вход в ВК, хотя при обычном открытии браузера он выполнен.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247336/selenium-use-of-firefox-profile